# Search can't find item in custom list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, custom-list

I have a custom list with a lot of items. The search sometime does not work.

For example if the title is

> ccc

even if I write

> ccc

directly in the search box it doesn't find the item even though I can see it on the list before I do the search . Even if I try like

> c*

or

> *c

While it can still find if I search for a single word in a more complex sentence.

For example like: "How are u?" if I search for "you" it finds this row. So how the search works and how can I find the simple single word matches?

I add some examples for the better understanding:

Here is the list:
[image]

Here are the search results:

[image]
[image]

Even if I click on the "Include" it not find anything.

Comment: in the search box you searching "ccc" or ccc

Comment: Simply ccc. So without the "".

Comment: try searching with ""

Comment: Sadly the same result.

Comment: what search are you using? the one with the list and not the site search box top right?

Comment: Yeah. The one at the top of the list, next to the Views.

Comment: interesting how long since you did it. might have to wait for the search service to kick in and index the text because it should work. I can recreate your issue but when its a new column and new data (rows) then search would fail but after the crawl it does find it

Comment: I added about 2 hours ago. And the strange part of it is that not all search fails. So if I try to search for several words in the texts some of them get the right results.

Comment: But I also can't imagine other reasons. I tested it with more then 1 day old elements and the search is working for them. So probably just need to w8. I ll confirm it a bit later.

Comment: im on sharepoint online and did the test and when new nothing when searching for ccc but after crawl it works fine.

Comment: May I ask u what do u mean by "crawl"? Also after 3 hours w8ing it started to works. So it was rly server indexing lagg as u mentioned. Thanks u very much for your assistance!

Comment: what i say crawl it means for the search engine to go through a table that says somthing has changed/added so it goes to that page to reindex it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wait for the crawl to occur before you can search. I did a test with a new column and data (row) filed in the field and as expected nothing. Waited until the search crawl occurred and is now visible. Im on sharepoint online so the search indexing is quick. If onpremise would depend on your setup. could be a whole day or half day or every hour/mins.

Comment: Yeah that was it! I had to w8 3 hours and now works. It was rly confusing, thanks u very much for the advice!

Comment: happy to help! :)